# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, stored-procedures, flask

I am sending in data to a stored procedure and am getting the truncated error.

```
 list_of_ids varchar(100)
 select * from table where id in (list_of_ids);
 id's are 1,2,3
```

If I send in one id it works.  A list of id's do not work.  How can I send in a list of id's.  Is there a list = true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare id to string:

```
select * from table where id in ('1,2,3');
```

Instead, you can use find_in_set-function.

```
select * from table where find_in_set(id, list_of_ids);
```

Comment: Cool. I sort of forgot about this.  Is the find_in_set method faster than inserting into a table then doing a select?

Comment: Most likely inserting into table and doing a join would be faster as a query (find_in_set may not use index), but unless you have huge amount of data, find_in_set is a good choise.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I am looking through a huge set of data.